# Unable to create outlet/action in view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I have navigation controller inside `UITabBar` object.

Tab Bar -> Navigation Controller -> View Controller.

For the objects which are inside View Controller, I am unable to create outlet/action.

Could you please help with this?

Comment: Need more information for answering exactly. To create IBOutlet you need to set
IBOutlet UITextView *textVew; in .h file

Comment: you need to add more details, where exactly you are facing issue.

Comment: I am trying to create an outlet by control drag from object to the .h file but nothing happens when i leave control drag (not getting the dialog box which helps in creating outlet/action)

Comment: (I assume your question is about using Interface Builder, not adding the outlet programmatically) Do you have the View Controller set as the File Owner of the View your are editing?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the class to your controller under Custom Class in storyboard?

You can check out this: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: Another way, which I had tried before, is to type your IBOutlet/IBAction properties in the .h file. Then, go back to storyboard, go to the Connection Inspectors, find the name you have defined and control-drag from the radio button to your objects.

Comment: Even that did not help. 

I deleted the file which getting referenced wrongly and added again in different. That solved the issue. Sounds like a some kind of weird caching issue. Thank you all for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct h file selected in the assistant editor view?
That's most of the times the problem with me...

Comment: Even I use to do that mistake. Now the problem is different. Even though, I have given different file custom class, while adding outlet, it shows different class.

How do i fix this?